# OpenQuery throws error with 'IN' clause

Tags: sql, ldap

I'm not able to execute the open query with IN clause, same query is execution with equal(=) operator. Below is my query-

```
DECLARE @SapNO as nvarchar(1000)
SET @SapNO = '''''00116795'''''     
DECLARE @str nvarchar(1000)

SET @str = 'SELECT top 100 Name,employeeid FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,
''select Name,employeeid  FROM ''''LDAP://ABC.com'''' 
WHERE objectCategory = ''''Person'''' 
AND objectClass = ''''user''''   
AND  employeeid in (' + @SapNO + ')   
'')'

exec sp_executesql @str
```

Above query throws the error message-

> An error occurred while preparing the query "select Name,employeeid 
>   FROM 'LDAP://ABC.com'  WHERE objectCategory = 'Person'  AND
>   objectClass = 'user'    AND  employeeid in ('00116795')    " for
>   execution against OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server
>   "ADSI".

If I replace the `IN` clause with equal operator, it works fine.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

LDAP doesn't support `IN`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746494(VS.85).aspx

Comment: So how can I select data for multiple IDs in on sql command. Any Idea?